# UIToolbar with UINavigationController sizing

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a `UIToolbar` as the `rightBarButtonItem` with my `UINavigationController`.  I create it like this:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 275, 44.01)];
```

In the iPad 4.3 simulator, it looks correct and lines up with the `UINavigationBar's` height.  But when I run it in the iPad 5.0 simulator, it looks too small.  Is there a certain setting for the height of the `UIToolbar` that is correct?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd avoid the entire category of these kinds of issues if you took advantage of Interface Builder and all it had to offer.

Do you have a specific reason for doing this in code?  Even if you insist on doing it there, you shouldn't be hardcoding your values.  You should be getting the width from the view's frame/bounds and/or putting the values into defined constants:

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, kStdToolbarHeight )];
```

Just curious, why do you have to toolbar height set to 44.01 and not 44.0?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to put a UIToolbar into the rightBarButtonItem with a UINavigationController is through code since Apple doesn't want to have multiple buttons with the UINavCtlr.  I did 44.01 because that's what most tutorials say to use, including those on SO in order to make the height look right.  At least that's the way it was done prior to iOS 5.  I don't know if it has changed now since I am seeing a height problem in one simulator and not the other.